# how to solve conflict problem betwwen TextGeometry from npm threejs-full and ExtrudeGeometry from forge autodesk viewer

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using Angular Forge Viewer component (ng2-adsk-forge-viewer npm library). In viewer I needed to add text so for that I am using TextGeometry from three-full-js (ref - https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-add-newest-threejs-features-forge-viewer), But the problem is that its getting conflicted with forge viewers default three.js library. I have created one custom shape using boxGeometry and Extrude Geometry using forge viewer three.js and text "A" using textGeometry of three-full-js but happening is that sometimes boxGeometry showing text "A" and textGeometry showing Box i.e rectangle. so I am unable to track whats going wrong.

Comment: Show some code. How are you doing your imports? maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714947/how-to-import-two-classes-by-the-same-name-in-javascript-es6) will help you.

Comment: import { Font, TextGeometry} from 'threejs-full-es6';
and forge viewer angular component has already in build three.js library

Comment: Show some code of where the problem is. "sometimes boxGeometry showing text "A" and textGeometry showing Box" sounds like a problem with your variables. Also [threejs-full-es6 is deprecated](https://github.com/Itee/threejs-full-es6#readme)