# use styled component with react js

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, styled-components

I have a problem with using `react-bootstrap` and `styled component` because when I need to style a component like `"Col"` after that I import that from two files like that :

```
import Col from "react-bootstrap";
import Col from "styled-Component";
```

so when I using `styled component` I should not use `react-bootstrap`??

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714947/how-to-import-two-classes-by-the-same-name-in-javascript-es6), will surely answer your question. and next time do a research first please. peace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to import with a different name:

```
import {Col as BootstrapCol} from "react-bootstrap";
import {Col as StyledCol} from "styled-Component";
```

Comment: thats what i mean when i use the Col like this it will do two jobs i mean will work like a styled component and grid ?

Comment: You can't have a single component be both at the same time, you must choose which component you are using, but this method should allow you to use both a Col from react and a Col from styled-component to be used in the same page in different spots.