# Firebase 9 and ref function with Vue composition

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage

I want to upload an image to firebase storage, version 9. I have working code for the firestore, but I cant for the life of me understand the firebase docs regarding uploading, and how to make it work for Vue (which also requires the import of a REF function).

**my question is:** How do I import the ref function in Vue and also import and use the ref function from firebase firestore?

This is what I have. It feels wrong to wrap the Firebase ref with a .value, but I just put it in there to get past the vue error.

vue component code fragment: <-- this works

```
if (imageFile.value) {
        await uploadImage(imageFile.value);
        console.log("image:" + url.value);
      }
```

useStorage.js <--this is where everything breaks down trying to convert from Firebase 8 to 9. Is it the vue Ref function?

```
import { ref } from "vue";
import { projectStorage } from "../firebase/config";
import { uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from 
"@firebase/storage";


const useStorage = () => {
const error = ref(null);
const url = ref(null);
const filePath = ref(null);
  
 //I need to use ref with firestore here
 const uploadImage = async (file) => {
    filePath.value = `images/${file.name}`;
    const storageRef = ref(projectStorage, 
  filePath.value).value;


   try {
     const res = await storageRef.put(file);
     url.value = res.ref.getDownloadURL();
   } catch (err) {
     console.log(err.message);
     error.value = err.message;
   }
 };

return { url, filePath, error, uploadImage };
};

export default useStorage;
```

config.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  [info]
};

// init firebase
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// init firestore service
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

// init firestore authorization
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);


const projectStorage = getStorage(firebaseApp);



export { db, projectStorage, auth };
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set an alias for either of the imports as shown below:

```
import { ref } from "vue";
import { projectStorage } from "../firebase/config";
import { ref as storageRef } from "@firebase/storage";


const fileRef = storageRef(projectStorage, filePath.value);
// use storageRef here ^^^ instead of ref from vue
```

Also checkout: [How to import two classes by the same name in javascript/es6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714947/how-to-import-two-classes-by-the-same-name-in-javascript-es6)