# Exporting/importing type and value with the same name

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, javascript-import

I'm trying to use [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/) with [toFormat](https://github.com/MikeMcl/toFormat) in typescript svelte 3 app. As explained on the GitHub page, I've installed types from DefinitelyTyped project:

```
npm install big.js
npm install toformat
npm install --save-dev @types/big.js
```

But, there was no type definitions for toFormat; so I wrote my own:

```
// toformat.d.ts
declare module 'toformat' {
    import type { BigConstructor, Big, BigSource } from 'big.js';

    export interface Decimal extends Big {
        toFormat(dp: number, rm?: number, fmt?: Object): string;
    }

    export interface DecimalConstructor extends BigConstructor {
        new (value: BigSource): Decimal;
    }

    export default function toFormat(ctor: BigConstructor): DecimalConstructor;
}
```

Now I can use big.js and toFormat like below (which works):

```
import toFormat from 'toformat';
import Big from 'big.js';
const Decimal = toFormat(Big);
console.log(new Decimal(12500.235).toFormat(2));
```

But, instead of executing toFormat each time when I use, I'd like to have the following simpler syntax:

```
import Decimal from '../utilities/decimal'; // both type and value are imported here
let amount: Decimal;
amount = new Decimal(23.152);
console.log(amount.toFormat(2));
```

For that I created /utilities/decimal.ts file:

```
import Big from 'big.js';
import toFormat from 'toformat';
export type { Decimal } from 'toformat';
export default toFormat(Big);
```

The issue now is that `import Decimal from '../utilities/decimal';` does import DecimalConstructor, but not Decimal interface. I saw that `import Big from 'big.js';` imports both Big interface and BigConstructor; so it seems possible to put both my Decimal interface and DecimalConstructor under the same `Decimal` name. Can someone help me with this?

UPDATE: BTW, the following works:

```
import type { Decimal } from '../utilities/decimal';
import DecimalConstructor from '../utilities/decimal';
let amount: Decimal;
amount = new DecimalConstructor(23.152);
console.log(amount.toFormat(2));
```

What I' like to achieve is to import both Decimal and DecimalConstructor under the same name as default import.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import two classes by the same name in javascript/es6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714947/how-to-import-two-classes-by-the-same-name-in-javascript-es6)

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error, I made it working the following way:

```
// /utilities/decimal.ts
import Big from 'big.js';
import toFormat from 'toformat';
import type { Decimal as Dec } from 'toformat';

const Constructor = toFormat(Big);
export const Decimal = Constructor;

// 'export default from' is not possible.
// See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35010
// and https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-default-from
export interface Decimal extends Dec { }
export default Decimal;
```

Ideally I'd like not to re-declare Decimal interface, but I couldn't find any better way.