# we can used react-router-dom and rect-scroll/module at same time in react.js? if yes then how to used?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, web-development-server, react-scroll

```
import React from 'react'
import "./Navbar.css"
import { Link } from 'react-scroll/modules';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

In my project I need to use react-scroll and react-router-dom at time in react app but

```
import { Link } from 'react-scroll/modules';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

here show error for import Two package.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714947/how-to-import-two-classes-by-the-same-name-in-javascript-es6

Answer (score 1):

You can import them like so:

```
import { Link as ScrollLink } from 'react-scroll/modules';
import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";
```