# Reactjs: redux toolkit with function same name

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is my code:

> a.tsx

```
const initialState = {
    open: false
}

export const a = createSlice({
    name: 'a',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        show: (state) => {
            state.open = true
        }
    }
});

export const {show} = a.actions;

export default a.reducer;
```

> b.tsx

```
const initialState = {
    open: false
}

export const b = createSlice({
    name: 'b',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        show: (state) => {
            state.open = true
        }
    }
});

export const {show} = b.actions;

export default b.reducer;
```

> app.tsx

```
import { show } from './app/reducer/a'
import { show } from './app/reducer/b';
```

And I get this error:

```
Duplicate identifier 'show'
```

I don't want to change method name to showA and showB.

How can I handle same name of functions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import two classes by the same name in javascript/es6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714947/how-to-import-two-classes-by-the-same-name-in-javascript-es6)

Comment: No, This is for redux

Comment: Are you sure? Looks like a modules import problem, rather than Redux.

Comment: Is there any solution except `AS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot import to things with same name in JavaScript, but you can rename it when importing:

```js
import { show } from './app/reducer/a'
import { show as showB } from './app/reducer/b';

show();  // reducer/a
showB();  // reducer/b
```

Comment: Is there any way to load all of reducer into one variable? like this: `import a from './app/reducer/a'; a.show();`

Comment: Yes. You could `import * as a from './app/reducer/a'`. You can find more on the import statement of ES6 modules here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

BTW: you're not importing the reducers here, but the action creator functions.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any other solution except to use AS.

Either you rename your functions in the original files, or you can use `as`:

```
import { show as showA } from './app/reducer/a';
import { show as showB } from './app/reducer/b';
```

If you want to learn more about imports, you can visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import